# Custom template for custom block

Tags: blocks, theming

I'm tying to show all the taxonomy terms from a specific vocabulary linked to the current node being viewed. I'm doing this with a new block defined in my module.

In my hook_block_view i need to give a $block['content'] a value, i'm putting a 'foobar' in it because i won't use it, and i add a new key 'tags' which is a array with my tags to render. Then in my block.tpl.php i check the block name and change the rendering if my custom block is rendered.

I guess there must be a better way of doing this...

I would love to add a custom template file, that will be used on my specific block. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a good article on what trying to do...

http://www.pixelclever.com/how-theme-specific-blocks-drupal

Comment: does not seem to work :(
Added a template with the name block-modulename-delta.tpl.php but Drupal didn't picked it up.

Comment: Make sure you have block.tpl.php in your theme folder. Also you will need to clear caches so Drupal recognizes the template you have added.

Comment: Yes i had/done that.

Comment: Put this in your theme template...  function YOUTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  print_r($vars['theme_hook_suggestions']);
} This should show you what the template should be called.

Comment: Great :) This gave me some more block info, and i got it to work by adding a template. Basically with the block--module--delta.tpl.php name.  Thanks!

Comment: Link doesn't works

Comment: Hey Alex, you should really improve/revisit your answer, which is pretty much a link-only answer and hence at risk to be deleted. After you edited it, please let me know about it via an extra "done" comment or so, ok?